# Check for a string in nested list at a certain element

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists, minesweeper

```
def isMineAt(gameBoard, row, col) : #doesn't work for some reason

    mainList = []
    mainList.append(row)
    mainList.append(col)
    print (mainList)
    mineAtLocation = False


    #compare the row and column guesses with gameboard[guess1]
    for i in range (GRIDSIZE) :
        for j in range(GRIDSIZE) :
            if gameBoard[mainList[0] == 'x' :
                row = True
            if gameBoard[mainList[2]] == 'x' :
                col = True

    if row == True and col == True :
        mineAtLocation = True
    elif row == False or col == False :
        mineAtLocation = False
```

I am calling my function with isMineAt(gameBoard, row, col)

Game board is a nested list I have initialised earlier and row and col are two integers that I am also passing in, and adding them to an array to compare againstmy gameBoard. I am getting an error however that is :

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Can you do `print(type(row), type(col))` and see if you're getting `class str`? Also, I don't get why you need to use your nested loops if all you're doing is checking the same values over and over again.

Comment: You're also missing a closing bracket here `if gameBoard[mainList[0] == 'x' :`. And not sure why you're accessing `mainList[2]` when that would be out of bounds.

Comment: You should check out https://github.com/redcricket/minesweep to get some tips on how to go about making a minesweeper game.